# Is it a good design to write the core main program in c++/shell script when the .so are in pure c?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ioctl

I would like to write a core main server handles request by user (in shell like enviorment) and load dynamic libraries executes ioctls and some debugfs. The core server is in c++ and the loadable libs are written in c. Is it a good design?

---

What about a shell script load the libraries and handles the request, is it possible at all?

Comment: Well, do *you* want to write your "main server" in C++ or C (or something else)? Although, unless there are other restrictions, why not write the "loadable libs" in the same language (whatever it is)?

Comment: Your second question - added in the edit - makes the whole question unclear and unfocused and might cause it to get downvoted or closed. Please decide on the one thing you want to ask about, and word it eloquently.

Comment: Some shells (`zsh` notably, and recent versions of `bash`) are indeed able to dynamically load (`dlopen`) shared libraries, but each such shell has its specific API and conventions for that. You'll need to focus on some chosen shell and adapt your shared libraries to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is designed with C compatibility in mind, so it is definitely OK to use libraries written in C from a program written in C++. The language even provides a syntax for using C headers with C++, so what you are trying to do is definitely possible.

In some cases, it may not be ideal from the readability standpoint, because C code may be using opaque handles to emulate objects: this is idiomatic to C, but not to C++. However, this issue can be easily adressed by writing a C++ wrapper around the C library, with very little overhead.

Comment: "C++ is designed with C compatibility in mind" - I've never had such a good laugh at someone being sarcastic :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, I think the designers initially aimed at a drop-in replacement ("a better C"), but eventually settled for a good compatibility.

Comment: @H2CO3 FYI, isn't that trivial to compile a c++ to be importable on ARM  based processors.

Answer (score 2):

The design in which a program or its part is written in C++ but interfaces to loadable modules in C is not unheard of. It is encountered wherever developers want to leverage the power of C++ (STL, exceptions) for the *implementation*, but want to retain C's simplicity and uniquity for the *interface* without dealing with, for example, subtle differences in how C++ compilers implement exceptions or RTTI. In Unix the additional reason is that there C++ has never taken off to the same level it did in Windows, so tooling support is still best for pure C.

An example of this would be third-party Python modules internally written in C++. Although implemented in C++, they communicate with Python using only C, as this is what the Python/C API expects. In some cases this communication can be rich - for example, C++ exceptions can be reported as Python exceptions and vice versa (Boost.Python does this automatically). The GTK-- toolkit allows writing GTK widgets in C++ and exporting their interface as regular GTK widgets.